# Issues with Imebra Dicom Viewer

Tags: android, intellij-idea, dicom, imebra

I'm trying to read a `dicom` file using the instructions given in "Adding Imebra to your Intellij Idea" and am facing issues with the same.

The exact code snippet where am facing the issue is this:

```
Stream stream = new Stream();
stream.openFileRead("/sdcard/Download/87FDH4G2.dcm");
```

The error I get is that the stream cannot be opened. I believe the error is due to the non-availability of `87FDH4G2.dcm` file on my machine.

My question is where should the location of `87FDH4G2.dcm` file be on my machine?

I am confused with this part: `/sdcard/Download/87FDH4G2.dcm`

Comment: Hello! Sorry, but I need some help. I added imebra_android.jar to libs folder but I take linkage errors.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you have such a problem is simple. You do not have "87FDH4G2.dcm" file on your Android device or emulator (Android Virtual Device). Using Android Device Monitor you can browse files and check if you saved a DICOM image in correct directory.